# View State Error Uploading Files

Tags: apex, visualforce, files, viewstate

I have a visualforce page that allows for uploading multiple files at one time (up to 10)  I have tested it several times in the sandbox and had no issues.  However, I am now getting intermittent view state errors in production.    The file (blob) is 1189.33 kb in the view state.  I have tried to upload about 6 times.  Three times I received the view state error, the other three I did not.

Are there any steps I can take to prevent the view state error?

Here is the entire class method:

```
public class OppFiles {
    // Deployed 04/2019 to add files using the opportunity wizard
    // and link the files to each opportunity on the wizard 
    // launched from the opportunitywizard page
    public PageReference returnPage { get; set; }
    public List<ExtendedDocument> docs { get; set; }
    public List<String> oppIds { get; set; }
    public blob file { get; set; }
    public String fileName{ get; set; }
    //List<blob> files = new List<blob>();

    public OppFiles() {

        docs = new List<ExtendedDocument>();
        for (Integer i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            ContentVersion a = new ContentVersion();
            docs.add( new ExtendedDocument(a));
           }
        String oppIdList = apexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('oids');

         if (oppIdList != null) {
            oppIds = oppIdList.split(',');
        }

        String ret = apexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('retUrl');
        if (ret != null) {
            if (oppIds != null) {
                returnPage = new PageReference(ret + '?t=documents&oid=' + oppIds[0]);
             }
            else {
                returnPage = new PageReference(ret);
            }  
        }
    }
    public PageReference SaveAndClose () {
        Boolean saveSuccess = Save();
         if (saveSuccess) {
            return returnPage;
         }
         else {
            return null;
         }
    }    
    public Boolean Save() {
        Boolean saveStatus;
        List<ContentVersion> CVs = new List<ContentVersion>();
        List<ContentDocumentLink> CDLs = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
            //Get the ContentVersion RecordTypeID for General FIles
            string CVRTID = [select id, name from recordtype where sObjectType = 'ContentVersion' and Name = 'Standard'].Id;
          for (ExtendedDocument doc : docs) {
              if (doc.file != null) {
                ContentVersion v = new ContentVersion();
                v.RecordTypeId = CVRTID;
                v.versionData = doc.file;
                v.Description = doc.odContentVersion.Description;
                v.Document_Type__c = doc.odContentVersion.document_type__c;
                v.title = doc.fileName;
                v.pathOnClient =doc.fileName;
                //add convtentversion to list
                CVs.add(v);
                file=null;
            }
         //end of for loop below
         }

        if(CVs.size() >=1) {
            for(ContentVersion CVSlist : CVs){
                try{
                insert CVSList;
                     for (id opid : oppIds)  { 

                            //create the contentdcumentlink to link the contentversion to each of the opportunities
                            CVSList = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = :CVSList.Id];

                                ContentDocumentLink cdl = 
                                new ContentDocumentLink(
                                ContentDocumentId=CVSList.ContentDocumentId,
                                ShareType = 'V',
                                LinkedEntityId=opid);
                                //CDLs.add(cdl);
                                insert cdl;
                        }
                saveStatus = true;
                }
                catch (DMLException e) {
                   //ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error uploading file'));
                   ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 
                        'Error uploading file');
                    ApexPages.AddMessage(msg);  
                saveStatus = false;
               }
            }   
         }
          else{
               ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 
                'You did not choose a file to upload. Please choose a file or Cancel');
              ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
              saveStatus = false;
          }
         return saveStatus;
    }

    public PageReference Cancel () {
         return returnPage;

    }

    public class ExtendedDocument {
        public blob file { get; set; }
         public String fileName{ get; set; }
        public ContentVersion odContentVersion { get; set; }
          public ExtendedDocument(ContentVersion a ) {
            this.odContentVersion = a;
            this.file = file;
                }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the exact view state error in your question?  Also, if you're hitting view state memory limits, consider using the `transient` variable modifier so that the uploads are not saved in the view state itself

Comment: Have you tried declaring your blob variable as transient? That should ensure that the blob is not retained in the view state.

Comment: Thank you both (Brian and Aayush) for responding.  The error is, "Maximum view state size limit (170kv) exceeded.  Actual view state size for this page was 187.735kb"   The strange this is that sometimes it won't throw the error with the same file.  I will try updating the blob file type.  thanks again!!!!

Comment: Unfortunately, This is still happening.  I did update the blob in my class to transient but I have not been able to add the blob in my the ExtendedDocument class.  Since I need to reach in and create that blob file I guess I cannot change it.  But the odd thing is that the error only happens once in a while.  I just got a call that it happened again.  When the user shared his screen and tried again, the file uploaded without the error.  Any other ideas?  thanks again!!!

Comment: I added a log on the user and the actual error is:  First exception on row 0; first error: UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW, unable to obtain exclusive access to this record or 1 records   I need to figure out how to refactor my code as that seems to be the real issue here.